# How to create a function that works out whether to use 'a' or 'an' before percentages

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown file that generates text based on various functions. e.g.

'the largest producer of whoopee cushions was  with a  of the market share'
Would apear as
the largest producer of whoopee cushions was Krusty's Komedy Supplies with a 34.3% of the market share

This works fine most of the time as you can put 'a' in front of most numbers, but 8, 11, 18, and the 80s need 'an'. I need to create a function to change a to an for those numbers. (and I can't just change the text to miss out 'a' each time).

Here's what I have so far

```
text.a.an.num <- function(bob) {
    if(bob %like% c("8%", "11%", "18%", "80%", "81%", "82%", "83%", "84%", "85%","86%", "87%", "88%", "89%")){
    paste0("an") 
  } else {
    paste0("a")
  }
}
```

This seems to give me back the 'right' answer but only if the numbers are exactly "8%", and goes wrong on "8.4%".

Comment: Although it's a legitimate question, and I'm not a native English speaker, do you really need a `a/an` here?

Comment: I agree I dont think you need the article "a" or "an" here - just "with xx percent of the market share" is correct. If you wanted to use "a" it would read "with a/an xx% market share". At any rate, to answer your question it'd be helpful to have some reproducible data.

Comment: If you can get rid of the % symbol you could apply the condition on ```floor(bob)```rather than on ```bob```

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't very good. In the actual R markdown with correct data, I do need the a / an and I can't change their wording at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments, I don't think you need "a" or "an" in the sentences. But if you had to you could use a regular expression to detect whether your string starts with 8, 11, or 18:

```
grepl("^8|11|18", bob)
```

Example:

```
for (bob in c("1%", "1.5%", "7%", "8%", "8.98%", "10.1%", "11%", "89.1%")) {
  print(c(bob, grepl("^8|11|18", bob)))
}

[1] "1%"    "FALSE"
[1] "1.5%"  "FALSE"
[1] "7%"    "FALSE"
[1] "8%"   "TRUE"
[1] "8.98%" "TRUE" 
[1] "10.1%" "FALSE"
[1] "11%"  "TRUE"
[1] "89.1%" "TRUE"
```